# set C macros in a make target?

Tags: macros, makefile

I have code with various parts which can be enabled or disabled with macros.
This can be done with #ifdef/#endif in the code, with -D options in the makefile and by calling make with setting the macro. Example:

```
make DOMP=-DUSE_OMP
```

In the makefile

```
calco.o: calco.cpp calco.h
    $(CC) calco.cpp -o calco.o $(DOMP)
```

in the code

```
#ifdef USE_OMP
#pragma omp parallel for
#endif
    for (i =0; i < N; i++) {
       ...
    }
```

I have quite a few of possible macros that can be set and would like to be able to have these set simply by making a different target. For example

```
make calc_abc
```

would build my application using a particular set of macros, whereas

```
make calc_xyz
```

would do this with a different set of macros.

I tried different approaches in my makefile, but found nothing that worked.
Is something like this possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use target-specific variables for this.  One of the features of target-specific variables is that they're inherited by their prerequisites.  So:

```
calc_abc : CPPFLAGS += -DUSE_ABC
calc_xyz : CPPFLAGS += -DUSE_XYZ

calc_abc : calc
calc_xyz : calc

calc: foo.o bar.o
```

Of course, the trick here is you must be SURE to run `make clean` in between these different types of builds, because otherwise you'll get a mishmash of objects built different ways.  If you think you'll commonly want to have things built different ways and co-existing, then typically you'd choose to put the object files in different subdirectories based on the type.  Then they won't interfere with each other.